# Excluding usages from Import Optimization in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a possibility to exclude

```
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;
```

from optimize imports done by PhpStorm. I would like do do this because optimize imports does not find usages of that class in annotations (but they exist), removes that line and as a result generates tons of bugs.

Comment: Do you have **PHP Annotations plugin** installed and enabled? If not -- install it. Any better?

Comment: I've installed it and now everything is fine. Thank You.